# Magento transactional mail logo replaced by default?

Tags: email, magento, graphical-logo

We are using magento 1.7.0.2 and there is a Transactional Mail logo option under the configuration -> design -> Mail Logo. We use this for a multiple store configuration, but only the main store logo shows up, the rest seems to be replaced by default or something like that. Is there a way to get back the specific store logo again?